# Is this an Oracle SQL bug?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a column named `TNAME` of type `nvarchar2(8)` in my table. Length is **8** as you see. There are a few records in the table and all of them has 8 symbols in that column. When I select that column the value contains **only 7 symbols**. If I `select length(TNAME) from mytable`, **result is 8!!!**

see the pic.
[image]

Why is this happening, any idea?

**ANOTHER PIC**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd say your GUI just has that column too narrow. If your query is indeed returning a row where the value isn't `'CMN00632'`, then yes, there is something horribly wrong because your DB doesn't know what `=` means.

Comment: I second Wooble's assumption. I too would suspect the GUI to cut off that 2 at the end.

Comment: NO. the width is not problem! @Wooble

Comment: Does it look? - wellcome.
That's the problem. the length is 8 and the value is 7.
there is CMN00632 in where and CMN0063 in result

Comment: @levi : double click the box next to `TNAME`...

Comment: If that `WHERE` clause is indeed producing the results you claim, you probably need to switch to a database that works. Although I suspect people would have noticed by now if `= foo` meant `LIKE foo%` by now in Oracle.

Comment: @levi : Do you think above query will return you this row??? forget `length(tname)` is giving 8 at this moment?

Comment: Now up-vote please (smirk)!

Comment: @levi : execute this query in command prompt... you will not see error...

Comment: @levi : no one will upvote for this question, I BET... check somewhere in setting, you have set that in column maximum 7 character data should be displayed.

Comment: @FahimParkar I know about noone :P.

The maximum character length is set to 8! and even if you select by procedure the results are correct!!! Thanks

Comment: @levi : see my answer. Try to execute `select '123456789' as test from merchants;` and see what you get...

Comment: Your reception might have been better if you'd asked what might be wrong rather than insisting this is an Oracle bug. It's clearly not an actual bug as [it _does_ return the correct result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbed1/1) normally.

Answer (score 4):

Let's be quite clear about this: Oracle is not the most expensive database in the world because it habitually asserts `('CMN00632' = 'CMN0063') is true`.  So the problem lies somewhere in your set-up, either in your environment config or in your data itself.

You remain adamant that there is no problem with your GUI.  There is no way for us to validate this.  However, if you're wrong, you're the only person who's affected so we'll just assume you're right.

The other possibility then is that your data is corrupted in some fashion, perhaps non-printing characters.  Is this problem affecting ebvery row or just certain values in the table?

Either way, there's a simple check you can run:

```
select dump(tname) 
from merchants 
where tname = 'CMN00632';
```

The output shoudl be the ASCII values for that string: `67,77,78,48,48,48,51,50`.

Incidentally it would be quite straightforward to prove that there is no truncating format associated with that column: *use a column alias* .  What does this query return?

```
select tname as some_new_name 
from merchants 
where tname = 'CMN00632';
```

Answer (score 3):

the query is correct. As you can see the record matches with your condition `CMN00632`. The reason why you are getting the result upto only `3` is because the GUI cuts off the value. Try to resize your column `TNAME` and you will see the whole value.

Comment: you're incorrect. The whole value is CMN0063 not CMN00632

Comment: @levi no, DerekFloss is correct. If the value were CMN0063, your query would return no results (since you have CMN00632 in your WHERE clause). Upvoted answer.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, No! it results and that the point!

Comment: @levi I don't know what you mean by "it results and that the point", but you *did* put "where tname = 'CMN00632" in your query, and therefore you won't get any results with tname 'CMN0063'. Since you seem to be using PL/SQL Developer, try running this in a Command window, or try increasing the column width (as has been suggested to you by others) - you will see that your column value is indeed 'CMN00632'.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in setting, somewhere you have set to display the column data **max to 7 characters**.

If you execute your query in command prompt, you will see proper result.

**Execute below query in your editor and see what it gives.**

**`select '123456789' as test from merchants;`**

I bet this will give result as **`1234567`** in your editor that you are using.

**Also one basic question**, ***Do you think you will get the row displayed in your image with the query you have?***

Comment: @levi : What you get for `select 'CMN00632' as test from merchants;`

Comment: @FahimParkar - any environmental formatting will be associated with the *column name* not the table.